# ssh via static route on different subnet hangs after approx. 30-40 s

Tags: ssh, routing, subnet, mikrotik

#### Before I had this setup:

`LAN: 192.168.1.0/24 (GW/router: 192.168.1.1) -> router 192.168.1.111 -> LAN2: 192.168.88.0/24`

First router/GW pfSense box, second router Mikrotik (with firewall etc.).

To access e.g. the host `192.168.88.10:22`, I had a port forward on the Mikrotik `192.168.1.111:30022 -> 192.168.88.10:22` so I could do this:

`ssh -p30022 192.168.1.111`

This was working fine.

#### New setup:

The purpose is to directly access hosts in LAN2 from LAN, to avoid having to manually forward a large number of ports.

Recipe:

Set a static route on the pfSense box: `192.168.88.0/24 -> 192.168.1.111`

On the Mikrotik add to the firewall:
[image]

(where bridge consists of this router's internal interfaces, i.e. `192.168.88.0/24`)

This appears to work well, i.e. `http` connections and `ssh` connections can be opened on hosts like `192.168.88.10` from the LAN.

However, `ssh` connections consistently hang after about 30-40 s. This is not a normal timeout (it works normally with port-forwards), so it must be related to routing/firewall.

I tested with:

```
❯ ssh 192.168.88.10 sh -c 'T=0; while [ 1 ]; do echo "Connected ${T} s"; T=$((${T} + 1)); sleep 1; done'
Connected  s
Connected 1 s
Connected 2 s
...
Connected 33 s
```

(then it hangs)

From hosts on the `.88.0` subnet I can access the internet and hosts on LAN fine, since I have the gateway for this subnet set to 192.168.1.1 (the pfSense box, which is my external router as well).

Any ideas?

EDIT: still no solution (after 1 month)...