# pfSense NAT to server in a second LAN subnet behind an internal second router (not working)

Tags: firewall, routing, nat, subnet, pfsense

I have a pfSense firewall/router that is exposing some services to my public ip.

This is working fine, as long as the service is on the primary LAN subnet (`192.168.1.0/24`), let's call it *LAN-A*.

E.g. this works:

```
public_ip:443 -> pfSense (NAT) -> 192.168.1.20:5443 (reverse proxy)
```

I additionally have a second LAN `192.168.88.0/24`, let's call it *LAN-B*, that is behind a *Mikrotik* router on `192.168.1.111`. In pfSense I have a static route for the network `192.168.88.0/24` specifying `192.168.1.111` as the gateway for it.

From *LAN-A* I can now connect to hosts in *LAN-B*, e.g. `192.168.88.10`, transparently, the same as to hosts in *LAN-A* (apart from a strange issue with `ssh` [mentioned here, still unsolved](https://serverfault.com/questions/1045291/ssh-via-static-route-on-different-subnet-hangs-after-approx-30-40-s)). (Hosts on *LAN-B* can also connect to the internet normally, because the *Mikrotik* router specifies the `pfSense` box on `192.168.1.1` as gateway to its clients).

So far so good. But now I want to expose a service on *LAN-B*, say `192.168.88.10:10000` via NAT on my external IP. So I do the same as normally:

```
public_ip:10000 -> pfSense (NAT+Rule) -> 192.168.88.10:10000
```

This, however, doesn't work (and `nmap` from outside shows the port as `filtered`, where within the LAN it is `open`). So it seems that the NAT logic doesn't know about my static route?

It seems somehow logical, because the static route "lives" in the scope of my local interface (`LANBRIDGE`) of pfSense, and the firewall (NAT) between `WAN` and `LANBRIDGE`, so it probably doesn't know the connection to `192.168.88.0/24` goes through `192.168.1.111`. But how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue (for later reference and possibly helps others):

The described setup (OP) is ok on the `pfSense` side.

The problem was that the *Mikrotik* router should forward (forward chain) for the actual source addresses (i.e. the ones connecting to the external IP), which would be `0.0.0.0/0` and not only addresses `192.168.1.0/24`. For security reasons the forward rule can be limited to certain ports if needed.